# Auth2 Object unidentified when trying to sign out (Angular2)

Tags: authentication, angular, typescript, oauth

Good Day,

I am trying to sign out an auth2 client. This process was working fine before I upgraded my router to fit in with new RC requirements. Now it seems as if the auth2 object is cleared or lost along the way from signing in to signing out.

Here is my sign out tag:

```
 <a role="button" (click)="signOut()" style="padding-left: 30px;">Log out</a>
```

it simply calls a signOut() function found in navbar.component.ts (See below)

```
signOut() {
    var auth2 = this._navigationService.getAuth2();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    });
    console.log('User signed out.');
    sessionStorage.clear();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['Login'])
    window.location.reload()
}
```

here is the navigationService code it is calling:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
onEditMode:boolean;
auth2:any;
constructor() {
    this.onEditMode=true;
}

getEditMode(){
    return this.onEditMode;
}

setEditMode(editMode:boolean){
    this.onEditMode=editMode;
}

setAuth2(auth2:any){       
    this.auth2=auth2;

}

getAuth2(){
    return this.auth2;

}

}
```

Here is my login.component.ts which sets the auth2 object seen in navigationService.ts:

```
onGoogleLoginSuccess = (loggedInUser) => {

    this.isLoading=true;
    console.log(loggedInUser)
    this._navigationService.setAuth2(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());

    console.log("Google gapi" + gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
    sessionStorage.setItem('gapi',gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());

    this._zone.run(() => {

        this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.hg.access_token;
        this.userDisplayName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        var strClientID = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['google-signin-client_id'].getAttribute('content')
        this.objTrimbleAuthentication.ClientID = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['google-signin-client_id'].getAttribute('content');
        this.objTrimbleAuthentication.IDToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

        this._trimbleAuthenticationService.sendAndVerify(this.objTrimbleAuthentication).subscribe(data=>{
            if(data.tokenIsValid==true){

                sessionStorage.setItem('S_USER_EMAIL',loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail());
                sessionStorage.setItem('S_USER_NAME',loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
                sessionStorage.setItem('S_ID_TOKEN',this.userAuthToken);

                this.objExternalBindingModel.ExternalAccessToken=this.userAuthToken;
                this.objExternalBindingModel.Provider="Google";
                this.objExternalBindingModel.UserName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();

                this._LoginService.obtainLocalAccessToken(this.objExternalBindingModel).subscribe(data=>{

                    // console.log(data);
                    this.isLoading=false;
                    this._router.navigate(['/Home']);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("access_token",data.access_token);

                },error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                })

            }else{
                this.isLoading= false;
                this.showModal('#trimbleAuthError');

            }
        }, error=>{

        })
    });
}
```

onGoogleLoginSuccess  is called from login.component.html:

```
 <div style="margin-left:8% !important" id="{{googleLoginButtonId}}"></div>
```

So this process was working fine until I update my router to use the latest Angular2 Release Candidate. I am out of ideas on what could possibly be causing the following error when I click the sign out button:

```
Error in component.html/navbar.component.html:12:33
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'signOut' of undefined
```

if you need any other information or components please ask I hope I have given enough information. As I said it was working so keep that in mind, please.

Comment: Are `onGoogleLoginSuccess()` and `signOut()` in the same class? If no, please post the `@Component({})` section of both class. Also need the `module.ts` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the solution i found to the above question was that signing out using localhost will not work. So i just used this block of code when deploying the website and keep it commented out when running the website on localhost.

this is my signOut() function found in navbar.component.ts:

```
signOut() {

    //////////////////////////////////////// Uncomment block for live deployment //////////////////////////////


    // var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    // auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    //     console.log('User signed out.');
    // });


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    sessionStorage.clear();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    window.location.reload();

}
```

although getAuthInstance gives an error when trying to run it in localhost, deploying the web application to a server seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Waiting for additional info ...

---

In the following code, `auth2:any;` is `undeclared`. Is `setAuth2` called anywhere before `signOut()`?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {

    onEditMode:boolean;
    auth2:any;
    constructor() {
        this.onEditMode=true;
    }

    getEditMode(){
        return this.onEditMode;
    }

    setEditMode(editMode:boolean){
        this.onEditMode=editMode;
    }

    setAuth2(auth2:any){       
        this.auth2=auth2;

    }

    getAuth2(){
        return this.auth2;

    }

}
```

---

Base on limited information and code posted, my guess is a logical bug in the logout process.

In `signOut()`, the `window.location.reload()` reload the page at the current url, which also clear all variables/objects. However, after reload, your app properly try to do signout again (due to url?).

In your `navbar.component`, you may need to add more logic in `ngInit()` to handle the situation.

Or can your code work without `window.location.reload()`? It seems odd to use that with angular2, especially with routing.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i took window.location.reload() out and the code still works. The problem happens before that line is executed though. The error occurs here:      var auth2 = this._navigationService.getAuth2();

Comment: And what do you mean by limited information? what would you need me to add and i will do so.

Comment: @AndreSmith Is it possible to upload your code into github?

Comment: @PaulR My original answer does not solve the issue, so I removed the content